# define a function in a c macro with a dynamic name coming from a function-like C macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

okay this sounds weird, the title is kinda
confusing but heres what i mean basically :

```c
#define make_name(id) cool_name_##id
#define my_cool_macro(id, type) void fun_##make_name(id)(type arg1)

my_cool_macro(hello, char);
```

this should expand to

```c
/*
 * passed through my_cool_macro
 *                 vvvvv
 */
void fun_cool_name_hello(char arg1);
/*   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
```

- `~` -- `my_cool_macro`
- `^` -- `make_name`

i dont have a better way to explain this,
any way to make this work ?

basically :

- define a function-like macro which can generate names
- define another function-like macro which calls to the defined name creating macro with an argument passed to the function creator macro

### why am i doing this

im kinda trying to implement templaces in c using macros and as you know templated functions can have different types and i want to mangle the names but not repeat the `cool_name_...` because what if i want to change the `cool_name` to `some_name`

the solution should also work similarly to my example, so `fun_##make_name(hello)` should work as should `hello_##make_name(hello)` and `ewuihewuifh_##make_name(hello)` without me needing to define a macro for every change

Comment: Why, pray tell, are you obfuscating your code? Make it readable. Saves people and probably yourself a lot of heartache in the future

Comment: @EdHeal im not obfuscating anything, im mangaling the names at pre-processing time

Comment: I apologise, but when a person post a question trying to figure out the preprocessor I think that the code is difficult to understand. But then again I am old fashioned

Comment: @EdHeal i annotated it if it helps

Comment: @EdHeal its not for readability, its for mangling, the person wont be accessing the function directly, but its like a helper, idk how to explain it, basically what im kindof doing is trying to somewhat implement templates in c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define join(x, y)  x##y
#define make_name_l(fn, id, arg_type) fn##id(arg_type)
#define make_name(fn, id, arg_type) make_name_l(fn, id, arg_type)
#define my_cool_macro(ret_type, id, arg_type) ret_type make_name(join (fun_, cool_name_), id, arg_type)

my_cool_macro(void, hello, char);

int main (void) {
    fun_cool_name_hello('a');
    return 0;
}
void fun_cool_name_hello (char a) {
    printf ("In function : %s, arg : %c\n", __func__, a);
}
```

---

**Additional:**

In case, if you want to make it work with any *type* or *number* of arguments then you can use ellipsis (`...`) and `__VA_ARGS__`.

```
include <stdio.h>

#define join(x, y)  x##y
#define make_name_l(fn, id, ...) fn##id(__VA_ARGS__)
#define make_name(fn, id, ...) make_name_l(fn, id, __VA_ARGS__)
#define my_cool_macro(ret_type, id, ...) ret_type make_name(join (fun_, cool_name_), id, __VA_ARGS__)

my_cool_macro(void, hello, char);
my_cool_macro(int, multiple_args, char, int, const char *);
my_cool_macro(void, no_args, void);

int main (void) {
        const char * str = "test";
        fun_cool_name_hello('a');
        fun_cool_name_multiple_args('x', 5, str);
        fun_cool_name_no_args();
        return 0;
}
void fun_cool_name_hello (char a) {
        printf ("In function : %s, arg : %c\n", __func__, a);
}

int fun_cool_name_multiple_args (char c, int i, const char * pstr) {
        printf ("In function : %s, c : %c, i : %d, str : %s\n", __func__, c, i, pstr);
        return i;
}

void fun_cool_name_no_args (void) {
        printf ("In function : %s\n", __func__);
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
In function : fun_cool_name_hello, arg : a
In function : fun_cool_name_multiple_args, c : x, i : 5, str : test
In function : fun_cool_name_no_args
```

---

https://godbolt.org/z/d67MWjasz

Comment: not really what im looking for, i would have to define a `make_name` for *every* `fun_` or `something_` or whatever, which im not looking for, im looking for something that can work with dynamic things, like `fun_##make_name(hello)` and `something_##make_name(hello)` and so on :) thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 1):

You could have a macro that creates the prototype along with its type, as well as one that makes your custom name.

```
#define name(f) cool_name_##f
#define make_function(type, name, arg) type fun_name(arg)
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define name(f) cool_name_##f
#define make_function(type, name, arg) type fun_name(arg)

make_function(void, name(hello), int);

void cool_name_fun_hello(int f) {
    printf("%d\n", f);
}

int main(void) {
    cool_name_fun_hello(1);
}
```

Comment: nooo i just realised this wont work well with my use case, i kinda need the `fun_cool_name_` to be dynamic, so like i could have anything there, im sorry, im super tired, its 4 am lol, but thank you for this, ig ill just work with what i got

Comment: In that case you can just pass directly into the first macro call, like `make_function(void, fun_cool_name_hello, int)`

Comment: Isn't that enough?

Comment: but then ill be repeating `cool_name`, i want that part to stay and only the `fun_` part to be dynamic, im sorry

Comment: @Ari157 I added a second macro to generate the name. It's not as clean as the accepted answer, but it's simpler.